# Automapper map registers (static data)

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, automapper, autofac

I have a DTO like this (note this is only a sample dto) :

```
public class SomeClassDTO
{
    public guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public IList<Register1> Registers1 {get;set;}
    public IList<Register2> Registers2 {get;set;}
}
```

and the class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}    
}
```

I need something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomeClass, SomeClassDTO>()
.ForMember(dto=>dto.Registers1, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>_session.Query<Register1>.ToList()))
.ForMember(dto=>dto.Registers2, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>_session.Query<Register2>.ToList()));
```

Where _session is an instance per request of the nhibernate session.
Ok, I need to get the collections in the dto populated from the values i get from DB using nhibernate session. (of course those collection has nothing to do with the class: SomeClass and they don't have any relations to it.
Dont know how to inject ISession to MapFrom or ResolveUsing.

The DI Container is Autofac, and the project type is WebApi2

Please Help

Comment: Why cant you just do                                     

Mapper.CreateMap<SomeClass, SomeClassDTO>()
.ForMember(dto=>dto.Registers1, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISession>().Query<Register1>.ToList()))
.ForMember(dto=>dto.Registers2, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISession>().Query<Register2>.ToList()));

Comment: Because i use webapi2 and DependencyResolver does not exist when i am doing automapper initialization. Infact DependencyResolver does not exist in webapi2 as I know.